# Creating a moving average of hms data using lubridate and xts/zoo

Tags: r, xts, zoo, lubridate

I have used `lubridate` to convert some duration data to hms format

```
library(lubridate)
series$Duration <- hms(series$Duration)
```

This gives me daily column data as an xts object:

```
>Duration

2016-03-12  9M 5s
2016-03-13  6M 18s
2016-03-14  6M 30s
2016-03-15  7M 12S
```

I was wanting to create a moving average from the data, so used:

```
Duration <- rollmean(Duration,30,align="right")
```

This does give a timeseries, however, not in a recognized format:

```
2016-03-12 32.10000
2016-03-13 32.26667
2016-03-14 31.53333
2016-03-15 31.16667
```

I'm not sure if the data is right and has somehow been converted to an index.It would not seem to equate to seconds.

My question is can I create a moving average of such hms data and keep the original hms formating

****Edit Note: apologies that I cannot provide example data right now. In contrast to my original post it appears that in creating the xts object, xts coerces the values as.numeric(), so the problem exists in changing the data frame to xts. However, trying to chart the dataframe data in ggplot also demands that the data be coerced using as.numeric().

In lieu of my providing data, I'd appreciate it if someone could offer help on how a moving average could be applied to hms data, and allow it to be charted without the coersion? Many thanks

Comment: Adding  a bit  of your original data would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the best route is to convert via period_to_seconds() first which allows you to chart accurately in seconds